# Writing to memory using pointer

Tags: c, memory, cortex-a8

I'm trying to write to memory using pointer as below, But it is writing to the unexpected address.

```
 uint32_t* pointer = (uint32_t) (__MEMORY_BASE)
 *(pointer+4)      = data;
```

While using the below its working as expected,

```
uint32_t* pointer = (uint32_t) (__MEMORY_BASE + 4)
*pointer      = data;
```

Can anyone please let me know, WHy I'm not able to use the first method to write to pointer address.

Comment: Learn about pointers and pointer arithmetics. `4` -> `1`. And use the ideomatic way to access hardware peripheral registers with the vendor-provided (CMSIS) headers. This code will not really work for other reasons, too.  If this accesses RAM: don't do this! Use the linker and sections.

Answer (score 4):

For any pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is equal to `p[i]`.

That means when you do

```
*(pointer + 4) = data;
```

you are actually doing

```
pointer[4] = data;
```

That means you write to the ***byte***-offset `4 * sizeof(*pointer)` from `pointer`. I.e. you write 16 bytes beyond `__MEMORY_BASE`.

To be correct either use the second variant, or use `pointer[1]` (or `*(pointer + 1)`) with the first variant.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint32_t* pointer = (uint32_t) (__MEMORY_BASE);
 *(pointer+4)      = data;
```

because of `pointer` has type `uint32_t *`, this means
that pointer + 1 = __MEMORY_BASE + 4, pointer + 4 = __MEMORY_BASE + 16,
this is how pointer arithmetic works in `C`.

Comment: First line triggers at least warning!

Answer (score 0):

`uint32_t` is a integer type of 4 bytes. Pointer addition in C is in terms (and in multiples of) the pointed type size.

So `pointer+4` adds 16 (4*4) to the `pointer` but in the second case you have an offset of 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not understand the pointer arithmetics

in the first one you add the pointed object (uint32_t) is 4 bytes long so is you add to the pointer 4 the actual address will be plus 4 * 4 bytes.

in the second example you add 4 to the actual address.